# Export DWG and TIFF with ArcMAP open in different locations in AutoCAD

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, autocad-map

I am trying to export some data from an ArcMAP I have, namely an aerial image (as a TIFF) and boundaries (as DWG).  Both files are on the same coordinate system.

I am trying to create some drawings in AutoCAD MAP.  I create a blank file and set the coordinate system to match the source data, and then import the two files.  However both data opens in drastically different locations, both of which dont match the ArcMAP?

I export both layers by right clicking->data->export and following the dialogs.

Strangely the DWG appears to be in millimetres when I attach it?

Is there a method to extract multiple layers in a batch process and force the coordinate system and units to match?

Comment: When you export the data from the layer right click,  the dialog box came up did you change the "Use the same coordinate system as" to set the data frame to match your data ?  If not, then you may have to go back and set the Data Frame Properties and then go to the tab "Coordinate System" and set your projection first and then try it again and export the data and select the data frame  Did you try this method ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of this issue. Sometimes the image units in AutoCAD would show up a "inches" so the scale would be wrong.  It looks like some of my drawings had the units set to Unitless.  I found that by making sure the drawing units were correct listed as Inches, and I set the drawing units to metres, the image would come in correctly.

Comment: You can accept your own answer